# How do I disable a shortcut file shortcut key that was already removed?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, file-shortcut, snipping

I set the "Shortcut key" in the Properties window of Windows' Snipping Tool to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, but I have since installed ShareX and I tried to set the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to ShareX and I removed it from Snipping Tool. However, whenever I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, Snipping Tool still opens even though it's "None" in the Properties window. How do I remove this shortcut? Is there a registry key I can delete?

I also tried to change the Snipping Tool shortcut in the Properties window to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, but it still only respects the first shortcut.

Comment: Have you tried a reboot after setting the new values?

Comment: Yes. I removed the shortcut from the shortcut file months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I had shortcuts to Snipping Tool in the following locations:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories
```

I had the shortcut set on the shortcut at the first location.

I had to:

1. Change the shortcut to something else, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.
2. Log out.
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> was still triggering. Set it to blank by pressing space bar.
4. Log out again.
5. I was able to set the shortcut in ShareX at this point.

Hopefully this helps anyone else with a similar issue.